# How to test internal store update in Jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Is it possible to test for object update in Jest, where that object is encapsulated inside a closure? I have a simple function like this:

```js
function example(){
  const store = {}

  return {
    updateStore(key, value){
      store[key] = value
    }
  }
}
```

If I need to test `updateStore`, I need to check if the store has been updated, but I have no access to the store in test. Is mocking a solution for this situation?

Comment: No, you can't mock it. Presumably the real thing also has a way to get values *out* of the store, test it's been updated using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it testable, you'll need to export either the store or some store-accessing method, so that the test can make assertions.

If you're writing your own store, as you are here, then this is a good idea.

If you're using a third-party store implementation, like Redux, you shouldn't test the store -- you should write tests that mock the store API and assert that your app code sends the right messages to the store.

Comment: I think the easiest solution is to export the store from the returning object, but then it will lost its privacy; if I use a store-accessing method, i think it will introduce additional coupling, where the test result of setting is now depending on getting. It seems testing with a store accessing method is more viable to me.

Comment: @JohnWinston What's the problem with privacy? The concept of encapsulation isn't supposed to be a footgun.

Comment: @EstusFlask I think privacy is valuable as a guarantee that all code which modifies app state takes a specific codepath: with Redux, that means calling `dispatch` and executing your "root reducer" which is shared by the whole app. It not only prevents state-modifying routines from unwittingly or deliberately accomplishing updates via mutation (which might otherwise be accomplished via immutability tech), it also ensures that your root reducer has visibility on all state changes made anywhere in the (potentially massive) render tree; that makes middleware portable, yielding stuff like reselect.